# Getting a proper decimal in Java?

Tags: java, double

I'm doing

```
double x = distance/maxRange;
```

And want x to be equal to 1/3 for example when distance = 10 and maxRange = 30 instead of 0.

How do I got about having it properly formatted?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean specifically `1/3` in console and not `0.33333...`

Comment: Are `distance` and `maxRange` both `int`s (or `long`s)?

Comment: Either or would work 1/3 or 0.3333 I have to take that number and multiple it by something else to be returned. I'm using doubles.

Comment: Oh sorry right, I thought if I made x a double it would cast it for me and I didn't need distance and maxRange to be doubles. My bad, thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why the result of 1/3=0 in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/why-the-result-of-1-3-0-in-java)

Comment: No way that 1/3 can be represented exactly in finite precision in decimal or binary. `0.333...` cannot be stored in any decimal type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double  x =  (double) 1/3;
System.out.println(x); // result print 0.3333333333333333
```

You must convert your calculation to double, else you will get 0.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `distance` and `maxRange` are ints, division will always result in `0`. What you have to do it turn one of them into a `double` to force it to do floating-point division:

```
double x = ((double) distance) / maxRange;
```

Answer (score 0):

**double:** The double data type is a double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point.

```
double z = (double) 1 / 3;
System.out.println("Result Using Double = " + z);
/*
Result Using Double = 0.3333333333333333
*/
```

double have 53-bit precision only see in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format.
So if you need more than 53-bit precision best option for it is used `BigDecimal`
For Example:

```
BigDecimal distance = new BigDecimal("1");
BigDecimal maxRange = new BigDecimal("3");
BigDecimal x = distance.divide(maxRange, /*precision-scale*/ 100, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println("Result Using BigDecimal=" + x);
 /*
   Result Using BigDecimal=0.3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
 */
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Comment: `double` doesn't have 64-bit precision, only 53 bits. And only `1.0/3` or `1/3.0` is needed, which is cleaner and shorter than casting